# Excel VBA err: Loop without Do

Tags: excel, vba

Something is wrong with the nested If statements, causing the Do loop error. If I simplify my If block to one item, it works fine. (I usually work in C#.NET in VS). This is supposed to be part of a simple form in Excel to aid data entry.

```
Private Sub cbDelete_Click()
If tbName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Sorry, please navigate to a non-blank row."
Exit Sub
End If

 Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""

'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value

If (tbName.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value) Then
     If (dpDateSubmited.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("B" & i).Value) Then
        If (tbLocation.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("C" & i).Value) Then
            If (tbBU.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("D" & i).Value) Then
                If (tbTitle.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("E" & i).Value) Then
                    If (tbDescription.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("F" & i).Value) Then
                        If (tbStatus.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("G" & i).Value) Then
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                            Exit Sub
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Item not found!"
End Sub


New fixed code:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If tbName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Sorry, please navigate to a non-blank row."
Exit Sub
End If

Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""

'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value

If (tbName.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value) And _
     (dpDateSubmited.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("B" & i).Value) And _
         (tbLocation.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("C" & i).Value) And _
             (tbBU.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("D" & i).Value) And _
                 (tbTitle.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("E" & i).Value) And _
                     (tbDescription.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("F" & i).Value) And _
                         (tbStatus.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("G" & i).Value) Then
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                            Exit Sub
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Item not found!"
End Sub
```

Appreciate all the help.
-RickH

Comment: close off all of hte `IF`'s with `End If`.

Comment: Looks like you have lots of "If" statements without "End If"s.
"If" will only work without an "End If" when the statement resides all on the same line.

Comment: Not sure where I'd place End If on all the lines. It's one whole logic structure, where everything needs to be true to del the row. Any failure loops to the top again.

Comment: With help from all the comments, I fixed my old code, even though I'll probably use Ralph's example as its much more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure yet, what you need. Still, I'd like to propose already a few changes to simplify your code block in the following way:

```
Private Sub cbDelete_Click()

If tbName.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, please navigate to a non-blank row."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim i As Integer

i = 3
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR")
    For i = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Non-SR").Range("A" & i).Value
        If tbName.Value = .Range("A" & i).Value And _
            dpDateSubmited.Value = .Range("B" & i).Value And _
            tbLocation.Value = .Range("C" & i).Value And _
            tbBU.Value = .Range("D" & i).Value And _
            tbTitle.Value = .Range("E" & i).Value And _
            tbDescription.Value = .Range("F" & i).Value And _
            tbStatus.Value = .Range("G" & i).Value Then
                .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End With

MsgBox "Item not found!"

End Sub
```

1. The `Do...Loop` has been removed and exchanged with a `For...Next`
2. All the `If` statements have been combined into one
3. A `With` block has been set to speed up your code and make the code shorter.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, much more elegant, and it actually works, compared to my code.

Answer (score 0):

If statements are code block. 
You can have a single line If statement

**VBA**

```
If a = 10 Then do_something Else do_somthingElse
```

**C#**

```
if(a = 10)      
   do_somthingElse;
```

Multi-line If statements must be closed

**VBA** Use End If to enclose the code

```
If a = 10 Then 
    do_something 
Else 
   do_somthingElse
End If
```

**C#** Use brackets {} to enclose the code

```
if(a = 10){
  do_somthingElse;
else{
  do_somthingElse; 
}
```

Your code opened 7 If statement blocks an closed 1 of them